# drop file in div and put it in file input

Tags: html, file, drag-and-drop

I have problem with dropped file in div
I want to put it in file input

I have this code

```
document.getElementById('drop_div').addEventListener('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.target.files || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);
    document.getElementById('file_input').files = files;
});
```

this code work perfectly in "Google Chrome" but no chance with other browsers

*the base from all this is uploading file using drag and drop without using ajax , if you have any other good method tell me

Comment: This is a question, but it helped me implementing a drop zone for uploading files. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will implement by setting the file input to be 0 opacity.

```
<div style='position: relative' id='drop_div'>
    <input type='file' style='position: absolute; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0);'/>
    <span style='position: absolute'>Drop Here</span>
</div>
```

and then add a onchange listener on file input.

Comment: Thanks , I think this is the last solution but it doesn't work with OPERA/SAFARI/IE